# Calculate Time Difference between 2 Rows in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am attempting to calculate the time between 2 events. I have the end time of event 1 in a row, and the start time of event 2 in a different row. How is this calculated in Spotfire. Its much more straightforward in Excel. Thanks!

Comment: Is your data in order by DateTime? Or better yet, could you provide a small data sample?

Comment: any update... your question may get closed if there is no activity